# The sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N

Tags: java, sum, challenge-response

I have to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.
example if we have to list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9,the sum of these multiples is 23.

Now the only problem left is that I want it to be able to read ALL the numbers THEN display the sum, for now it reads one number and display the sum right after it, any ideas?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int Nbr = Integer.parseInt(line);


        for(int j=0; j<Nbr;j++)
        {
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line2 = br2.readLine();
            String[] numbers = new String[Nbr];
            numbers[j]= line2;
            System.out.println(Somme(Long.parseLong(numbers[j])));
        }

        }


public static long Somme(long Nn) {
    long s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Nn; i++) {
        if (((i % 3) == 0) || ((i % 5) == 0)) {
            s = s + i;
        }
    }
    return (s);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). I would also suggest you add to a `sum` by iterating from `3` to `n` in increments of `3`. Then from `5` to `n` in increments of `5` (then exclude the multiples of `3`, because they've already been added). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(getSum(n));
    }
}

public static long getSum(int n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 3) {
        sum += i;
    }
    for (int i = 5; i < n; i += 5) {
        if (i % 3 != 0) { // <-- already added if i is divisible by 3
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Based on your comment below, change `main` to first read the `int` of counts, then store them in an array. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int toRead = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] vals = new int[toRead];
        for (int t = 0; t < toRead; t++) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                vals[t] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int n : vals) {
            sb.append(getSum(n)).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works almost same as mine, what I want to do is, the first int that I'm going to read is the number of the numbers that I have to calculate the sum for, for example this input : 3 
10 
100 
150 

3 means there will be 3 numbers which are 10, 100 and 150, the output should be : 
23 
2318 
5175.
 and not display the sum right after the input

Comment: @Hadh Edited. Next time please include all relevant detail in your original post for more (and better) help sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Move your print statement outside the loop.

Before loop,

```
long[] sumArr = new long[Nbr];
```

inside loop,

```
sumArr[j] = Somme(Long.parseLong(numbers[j]));
```

after loop,

```
for (long sum : sumArr) {
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to read all Ns first then ,read them and put them in an array then try to find the sum

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ArrayList` and add the sum to it then print it after the loop

Answer (score 0):

As we know that we need to sum of those numbers which are divisible by 3 or 5 below n where n=10 or 100 or more (it is limit). But if we have n=20 so 15(15%5==0 && 15%3==0) will come twice so that we need to add only once so that  we need to check a number is divisible by 15(since 5*3=15).

```
   long n1=0,n2=0;
    int i=1,j=1;
    while(3*i<n)
        {
        n1 +=3*i;
        i++;
        if(5*j<n)
            {
            n2+=5*j;
            if(5*j%15==0)
                n2 -=5*j;
            j++;
        }
      }

    System.out.println(n1+n2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            long n = in.nextInt();
            for(int j=1;j < n;j++)
            if(j % 3 == 0 || j%5 == 0){
                sum+=j;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum = 0;
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

This is simple Solution